# JPA - Get updated/synced entities across EntityManagers (refresh)

Tags: java, jpa, architecture, eclipselink

I'm learning JPA. My provider is EclipseLink, and I'm making desktop application, and using application managed EntityManager.
In DB, I have table B that references table A, which means that entity class A has list of Bs (and it also has some other lists).
Here's simplified situation:
I have four ways/scenarios to make changes made by method below visible in calling method and it's EM.

```
void addB(A a, String desc){
   EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   mngedA = em.find(A.class, a.getId());
   B b = new B();
   b.setDesc(desc);
   // option 1:
   b.setA(mngedA);
   em.persist(b);

   // option 2:
   a.getBList().add(b);

   em.getTransaction.commit();
   em.refresh(a); //needed in some scenarios
   em.close();

}
```

In calling method I have this:

```
em = factory.createEntityManager();
A a = em.find(A.class, id);
println(a.getBList().size());
addB(a, "value1");

//em = factory.createEntityManager(); //1
//a = em.find(A.class, id);           //2
//em.refresh(a);                      //3

println(a.getBList().size());
```

Marked lines could be commented and uncommented, and I figured out 4 combinations that makes second println call print bigger number than first.
These are:

1. Use option 1 in addB (persist new entity directly), use refresh in addB. In calling method use only a = em.find... (comment lines marked with 1 and 3).
2. Use option 1 in addB, but use refresh only in calling method (uncomment line //3 keep line //2 commented).
3. Use option 1 in addB but don't use refresh in addB, use refresh in calling method, and "find" A again using new em (uncomment all 3 lines). (almost same as 2. but interesting because of performance)
4. Use option 2 in addB, don't use refresh at all, uncomment all 3 lines in calling method.

First combination is slowest, it takes most SQL queries. At refresh it loads everything.
Second and third combination is in the middle, at refresh it loads only changes from DB.
Fourth example is fastest, it doesn't require any additional queries to DB.

Can someone make comment to all of this confusion, **how and why this works?**

**What is the right way to do it and is there a way to achieve effect of fourth combination without creating new EM, but use existing?**

If I want to make big and complex desktop application, that maybe has concurrent access do DB, **what approach should I have?**

Thank you.

Comment: Is this really so difficult to answer? I knew it, JPA is not intended to be ease to use. So it's just ORM and DB abstraction layer. Am I wrong?

Comment: What you are asking for is not an answer to a simple question -what you are asking requires an indepth tutorial on JPA.  There are numerous that go into explainations indepth to what you are seeing if you query.  There are numerous ways to do the same thing, so asking for a 'right way' won't give you great answers as it is opinion based.  Most of what you are asking can be explained by JPA allowing for 2 levels of caching.  1st at the EM level and the second at the EMF level.  See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching for some caching info

Comment: Some questions on what you are after - why are you using multiple EMs?  If you are just trying to read and merge some changes, do you really need to branch the method into a different context?  Why are you trying to use refresh at all?

Comment: @Chris well, It's just for learning purposes mostly. I'm looking for good way to organize application architecture. And I saw that NetBeans generated Controllers are using different EM every time, but gave up on using them because there ware some bugs.

Comment: @Chris I also looked into many tutorials but none explains why in first situation fresh loads all information from DB, and in fourth I don't need refresh at all. I have already enabled shared cache. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use a different EntityManager context, remember that entities loaded outside of it are not apart of it, so changes made to mngedA are not reflected into A unless you force the refresh once the transaction is done.  EntityManagers are designed to be used similar to transaction scopes, so seperate EntityManagers are intentionally issolated from each other.

There are any number of solutions for what you want, but if your client is long lived, you might not want to keep a single EM around for its life, as it does contain a cache that will fill up and become stale.   Instead, you might want to obtain one for reads as needed, and either clear it when done, or throw it away and obtain new ones as needed.  Something like:

```
A saveAndAddB(A a, String desc){
   EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   mngedA = em.merge(a);
   B b = new B();
   b.setDesc(desc);
   b.setA(mngedA);
   mngedA.getBList().add(b);;
   em.persist(b);
   em.getTransaction.commit();
   em.close();
   return mngedA;
}
```

This will save any changes to A, and return the up-to-date copy from the latest EntityManager.  Your application would then keep using this A instance if needed:

```
  em = factory.createEntityManager();
  A a = em.find(A.class, id);
  em.close();//no longer needed
  println(a.getBList().size());
  a = addB(a, "value1");

  println(a.getBList().size());
```

An alternative if your process is short lived is to pass the EM into the method, so that all changes can be picked up in the same transaction, but it is more common to pass around detached A instances and merge them into transaction as required.  If you don't want to pick up changes to A, you might pass around A's ID to the addB method instead.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing...what are reasons of keeping one EM for long period and across methods? For how long it should be kept, and should it be kept across classes? I hope it will give me an answer to what is better for typical desktop application.

Comment: There isn't really a great reason to make it long lived, as EntityManagers are meant to be light weight.  They do have their own issolated cache, so that is both a benifit and draw back.

Comment: But I saw in some tutorials people put someing like this in a class @PersistenceContext(unitName="PU") 
EntityManager em; 
So it lives as long as object lives, and also use @TransactionAttribute for methods. I know what this does, all tutorials explain it, but they tend not to explain what specific approach is good for, what kind of situation. Thank you. And sorry for bothering you.

Comment: I have found a reason where having separate EMs for every method is not best solution. Well at least not if these methods are simple CRUD operations. If I want to commit few changes to DB and want to do it in single transaction. Then I can have one big method that does it all, or few methods that do NOT have their own EMs.

Comment: There is too much choice, more is less, sometimes. :)

Comment: the PersistenceContext(unitName="PU") annotation lets the container inject a context as needed, and manages its lifecycle.  It does not live as long as the object it is injected into, but gets injected into it based on the calling context as controlled by the container.  Find tutorials that match your use cases, as I'm not sure principles that apply to apps deployed to containers apply to desktop apps.